# Can a PC have more than one deity whom they worship?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, religions-and-deities

Can a PC worship more than one deity, and if so, what would be the pros and cons?

Comment: Are you asking about deities in the same pantheon, or a different situation? (I am reviewing *The Complete Divine* at the moment, and find your question to be related to something that I am looking up).

Comment: Do you have any reasons to believe it might be limited to one, or that there are mechanics for many? Adding why you are asking helps answerers better answer your question.

Comment: Could you be more specific about your definition of “worship?”  Is it mere lip service to deities?  Is it allegiance?  Is it devotion?

Comment: I'm thinking prayer, offerings, and to the beat of my PCs ability following the Tennant's of the deities.     I'm also confused on how it works if a clergy follows more than one diety do they gain proficiency in both dieties favored weapons and both their domains?

Comment: @Korvin I'm planning on him being an escaped slave from (insert evil entity here) who since then has just been traveling around doing whatever in the mean time while picking up bits of gossip, skills, and religion ever since. So even he is unsure about pantheons only that some dieties appealed to him and he decided that he would devote himself best he could with his limited knowledge while traveling and trying to find himself as well as seeking justice.

Comment: What is the PC's (intended) class?

Comment: Debatable. Trying to play it by ear at the moment. I mean former slave, possibly a diety/hellish etc. experiment, turned drifter and slightly unstable CN helping hand.  Thinking slave was used for multiple purposes including enforcer and gladiator. Father was a smith and taught what he could before everything hit the fan.

Comment: Belief system is made of mismatched hodgepodge of things heard and learned since then.  Was kinda wanting to go a barbarian shaman route but then the possibly ranger or druid thing kicked in.   Honestly there's a lot going on.

Comment: @Bradley Lindsey  Welcome! I have tried to answer this as best I can with the information you shared in the comments. I hope this if of help, or can direct you to the original source material. If you decide on a concrete example, you could open a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, in theory

However, if you are looking at game mechanics of 3.5 and you are looking at a class that depends on divine magic/favour, then you would normally need to choose a patron god or "a cause or source of divine power". (PHB p. 30)

The materials for 3.5 suggest that mechanics of classes that rely on divine magic need to be prudent about who they worship - otherwise, the well that sources their magic might just run dry. Or worse!

> Divine Spells - Clerics, druids, experienced paladins, and experienced rangers can cast divine spells. Unlike arcane spells, **divine spells draw power from a divine source**. Clerics gain spell power from deities or from divine forces. The divine force of nature powers druid and ranger spells. The divine forces of law and good power paladin spells. (PHB p. 179)

If the class relies on divine magic, the PC's alignment needs to be not more than one step away from patron god's alignment. You will find information on the Alignment in Chapter 3, Classes. 
For example in the case of a Cleric:

> **Typically, a cleric is the same alignment as his deity, though some clerics are one step away from their respective deities in alignment**. [...] **Some clerics devote themselves not to a god but to a cause or a source of divine power**. These characters wield magic the way clerics devoted to individual gods do [...] A cleric devoted to good and law, for example, may be on friendly terms with the clerics of lawful and good deities and may extol the virtues of a good and lawful life [...] **A cleric’s alignment must be within one step of his deity’s** (that is, it may be one step away on either the lawful–chaotic axis or the good–evil axis, but not both). [...] A cleric may not be neutral unless his deity’s alignment is also neutral. (PHB pp. 30-32)

I don't see there being any problem with **worshiping another god or gods**, as long as the lore does not suggest that the gods in question are at odds with each other. **This is suggested in the source materials**:

> The typical person has a deity whom he considers to be his patron. Still, **it is only prudent to be respectful toward and even pray to other deities when the time is right**. Before setting out on a journey, a follower of Pelor might leave a small sacrifice at a wayside shrine to Fharlanghn (god of roads) to improve his chances of having a safe journey. **As long as one’s own deity is not at odds with the others** in such an act of piety, such simple practices are common. (PHB p. 106)

To contrast the example, if a Cleric whose divine magic relies on the LG patron god Moradin LG, begins to regularly pray and worship the CE Orc god Gruumsh, they may find themselves in rather nasty pickle. This not only goes against the principle of similar alignments but would go against the lore because these two gods are in direct opposition. The outcome may be that Moradin revokes his favour, or much worse.

> Gruumsh [...] harbors a special hatred for Corellon Larethian, Moradin, and their followers. (PHB p. 107)

Always look towards the alignment of the god. **If the secondary god's alignment is in direct conflict with the alignment of the patron god, I would suggest that this does not work.** There is a helpful table from the Hierophant section under prestige classes to determine direct opposition (DMG p. 189).

> **Table of Opposed Alignments**
>
> - Lawful good -- Chaotic evil
> - Neutral good -- Neutral evil
> - Chaotic good -- Lawful evil
> - Lawful neutral -- Chaotic neutral
> - Neutral* -- Lawful good, chaotic good, lawful evil, chaotic evil
>
>   - A neutral hierophant chooses one of these alignments to be the one that he opposes, for the purposes of this special ability.
> - Chaotic neutral -- Lawful neutral
> - Lawful evil -- Chaotic good
> - Neutral evil -- Neutral good
> - Chaotic evil -- Lawful good

I would suggest reading in detail the sections on **Alignment and Religion in Chapter 6 of the PHB** (pp. 103-109) as well as the section on **Religion in Chapter 5 of the DMG** (p. 143) before making any final decisions.

The final choices will be entirely up to you as a DM to decide.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot.  What I started thinking is that mostly this guy is a follower of a diety (still looking into it) who helps those who were wronged or enslaved or something. The problem is that I did download play stores 5e complete thing and have been glancing through it since I couldnt find one for 3.5 though the d20 one says it is interchangeable with 3.5.  And I think I'm leaning towards Kratos the god of war or Kovas the Blade maybe, but with a strong alignment towards Aphrodite or one of her counterparts.

Comment: I would love to find a love goddess who is also a battle lover. And to my previous comment I'm not sure if those are even playable for 3.5 since the d20 app is irritating trying to navigate it.

Comment: @BradleyLindsey As hinted at in this answer's opening, a *3.5* cleric in the default setting can also have *no* deity and, "If your cleric is not devoted to a particular deity, you still select two domains to represent his spiritual inclinations and abilities" (*PH* 32). So, for instance, a cleric can be devoted to freedom and love; she needn't have found a deity that represents freedom and love first *then* devote herself to those ideas.

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan      Okay that is exactly what I needed to know! Thank you!

Comment: @BradleyLindsey You're welcome, but be aware that the option isn't available in all settings (e.g. I'm pretty sure clerics of no deity are forbidden in the Forgotten Realms). Still, ET got home, I recommend updating the answer with this information since the asker found it useful. (Making this alone my own answer seems indulgent when yours covers extensively so well all the other ground.)

Comment: @Hey I Can Chan   Ahh didnt realize that thanks definitely have to do a bit more research.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thank you - will do. Do you have the name of the source material so I can add it in?

Comment: It's from the [cleric class feature](http://dndsrd.net/cleric.html#cleric-class-features) Deity, Domains, and Domain Spells in the *Player's Handbook* on 32.